# ndgrid - input and output from cell array

Tags: scilab

I am converting some code from Matlab to Scilab and ran into trouble trying to use Scilab 'ndgrid' function with input and output from cell array. 
Specifically, I use ndgrid with an a priori unknown number of vectors (contained in a cell array) and intend to get the output grid matrices in a cell array.

In Matlab the code looks like that:

```
    v = {0:3,0:3}; // not necessarily of length 2 (dynamically set)
    G = cell(1,2);
    [G{:}] = ndgrid(v{:});
```

I can't obtain similar behaviour using Scilab (neither for the input, nor for the output).
For the input, Scilab returns `ndgrid: Wrong type for argument #1: Booleans, Integers, Decimals, Complexes, Polynomials, Rationals or Texts expected.`

I hope a workaround exists. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: For the input, the solution is actually to write `ndgrid(v{:}(:))`
Still looking for the output

Comment: Replacing an explicit list of output arguments by an implicit list is currently not supported in Scilab but could be an interesting feature. We could consider it for the next release.

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneMottelet for your answer! In the meantime, I simply created my own `ndgrid` function that returns a cell array, which solves my problem

Comment: By the way, if you don't need several dimensions I would recommend the use of lists instead of cells. Lists are native objects in Scilab since the beginning and are far better supported than cells (included for Matlab compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

```
v = list(0:3, 0:2);  // not necessarily of length 2 (dynamically set)
G = list();
c = strcat(msprintf("G(%i)\n",(1:length(v))'),",")
execstr("[" + c + "] = ndgrid(v(:))")
G
```

does it:

```
--> c = strcat(msprintf("G(%i)\n",(1:length(v))'),",")
 c  = 
  "G(1),G(2)"

--> execstr("[" + c + "] = ndgrid(v(:))")
--> G
 G  = 
  (1) : [4x3 constant]
  (2) : [4x3 constant]
```